# Show touches during Testing

Tags: android, touch, android-espresso

I am testing my app with Espresso automated testing. I have to screen capture the testing. The problem is it's not visible in the screen recording as to where the touch event is occuring. I have enabled "Show Touches" from developer options too but still touch events are not shown during Espresso testing, however they are visible when I touch the display.

How can I enable show touches so the touch events are visible during espresso testing?

Comment: Show your code. It's hard to tell anything without seeing what you're doing.

Comment: There is nothing to see in code. the click() method of espresso is supposed to show a Touch Icon when Show Touches is enabled

Comment: I tried this manually and Espresso doesn't seem to show any touches, though if I click with my mouse they do show. I expect Espresso bypasses the show touches entirely and there's nothing we can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only solution right now you need to enable it in the phone manually before starting the test.